# How to change table base layout of concrete 5

Tags: layout, concrete5

Hi i am new with `concrete5`. The problem is that the shop page have layout in `table base`, Now i want to change the table base to div base so that i make my site `responsive`. But i did not find the `HTML` code for this to make changes. Here is my site [link](http://www.peekboutique.co.uk/).

Answer (score 0):

The core eCommerce addon comes with alternate div based (and table free) custom templates for the product and product list blocks. These are intended for styling with css, either directly, or as the basis for further template development.

Comment: Hi thanks for this. can you tell me how to show all post of blog,means code for displaying the all posts

Comment: That is nothing to do with the initial question and should be asked as a new question.